# Problems to get a dynamic var in javascript - eval()

Tags: javascript, eval

I have a simple problem to solve, I know how to do it in PHP but have no ideia how to do it in javascript.

I gave a dinamic form, with N lines.

```
// HTML
<form>
$total = 0;
for($x...){
?><input type="text" name="field<?PHP echo $x; ?>" onChange="f5(this.form,<?PHP echo $total; ?>)" />
$total++;
}
</form>
```

//Js

```
function f5(formulario,total){

math = 0;
    for(numero=0; numero<=total; numero++){
        var foo+eval(numero) = formulario.quantidade+eval(numero).value
        math = math + foo+eval(numero);
    }
}
```

In Js I need to get all values of the form and do some maths and send it back to the html.
Anyone have an example of how do that? I am trying to use eval() funcion with no sucess.

Regards,

Thanks,

Comment: Personally I dislike non-English names in code because it requires constant language switching which detracts from reading the code.

Comment: @Bernard: You expect all programmers whose native language is not English to use English names? That's so American!

Comment: Bernhard and Juan, I think you both are write. I try always I can to translate the code to english, but sometimes we dont have time to do that. A word for that "comprehension". Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the bracket operator to access a dynamic property

```
function f5(formulario,total) {
    var math = 0;
    for(var numero=0; numero < total; numero++){
        math += Number(formulario["field" + numero].value);        
    }
    return math;
}
```

Here's a live example http://jsfiddle.net/WFdZJ/

Comment: Juan Mendes, Thank you very much. Thats was great.